# Handle browser back button when http post request and no caching

Tags: caching, browser

when clicking the browser back button with Http POST request, the browser was displaying "Webpage has expired" message.in my application response header set by "cache-control:no-cache". if i can set cache-control:private/public it works fine.but without changing the cache-control how to handle this back button issue especially in IE7?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Post/Redirect/Get pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get